# Is there a way to have a link in Internet Explorer that opens in a new browser (Chrome / FireFox / etc.)?

Tags: javascript, php, internet-explorer

I think my topic clearly states my issue, but some more information:

1. This is for an internal application, so we have complete control over the user's workstation, can turn off pop-up blocking, etc.
2. They HAVE to start in Internet Explorer.  I know Firefox has some good plugins for opening links in other browsers, but unfortunately they will not be starting in Firefox.
3. I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require the user to do anything but click the link in question, but if necessary some kind of right click -> select new browser solution (like some of the FireFox plugins I looked at have) would be ok.

We're currently writing all of our code in PHP / JavaScript / HTML.

Comment: Long time ago, Firefox registered a "firefoxurl:" protocol during its installation, which had lead to some security exploits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ActiveX.

In this case, all the user would have to do is to consent with a warning:

> An ActiveX control on this page might be unsafe to interact with other parts of the page. Do you want to allow this interaction?

Also, the user would need to specific allow your page to run ActiveX scripts. (*Allow in the security settings. It's not set by default*)

If the user allows it, you can use the ActiveX Object `WScript.shell`, to run a command in the client's machine. Call the `.exe` of the target browser, passing the page to open as the first parameter (It works, at least in firefox and chrome):

```js
//Works only if opening from IE:

document.querySelector("input").onclick = function() {
  var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
  objShell.run('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" "http://www.google.com/"');
};
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Teste" />
```

Comment: I'm actually a bit unfamiliar with ActiveX.  Is this something that needs installation on the server to use?  We're using a LAMP server if that information is relevant.

Comment: ActiveX is a framework developed by Microsoft, that comes embed in client's IE browser. It needs to be enabled though.